# What command like Top will provide client IP visibility?

Tags: linux, ssh, top

I am fairly new to sysadmin and running an apache Linux server - I like to live monitor traffic on my instance in solarputty using TOP

TOP is great, but I can't seem to find a suitable command that will let me also see the incoming client IP.

Ideally, I want a command similar to TOP so I can see PID, USER, CPU, MEM etc, but also show the incoming visitor address (Client).

Which command could provide that?  Or is there a better interface other than solarputty?

Answer (score 1):

I’m not aware of a tool which provides process monitoring *and* separate connection monitoring simultaneously, but there are ways to work around that.

To keep an eye on network connections, I use [`iftop`](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/), which is available in most distributions. This shows bandwidth used per connection:

[image: iftop showing connections details with host names and IP addresses, and instantaneous bandwidth used]

You can use a tool such as [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) to split your screen in two, showing `top` in one half and `iftop` in the other, if you want to see both simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You can use many tools.

1. `mod_status` - this will help you view on web page current visitors IPs for example
2. `lsof` - command line tool to get open files (network connection is also file in sense of UNIX/Linux)
3. `netstat` - almost like point 2 but only for network connections
4. `tail` - list last lines from file (access.log in your case)